# javascriptでのrestを使用した再帰処理について

Tags: javascript

javascriptで下記の再帰処理プログラムを書いたのですが、なぜ動作するのか分りません。
restに入る配列がheadに代入されて行くのですが、配列の値が無くなり最後はundeindで空の配列が帰ってきそうなのですが、２倍された配列が帰って来て不思議です。どのような動作をしているのでしょうか？

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];
 
function double([ head, ...rest ]) {
    console.log(head);
    if (!head) { return []; }

    return [ 2 * head, ...double(rest) ];//rest[2, 3]がhead, ...restに分割されて入る
    // [2 * head = 1, 2 * head = 2, 2 * head = 3, ここにこずreturn 2 * head = undefind]
}
```

**追記**
処理の流れを自分なりに解釈してみたのですが、やはり最後に空のリストが追加されそうな気がします。

[1, 2, 3]と配列があって分割代入になり
最初の処理1

```
head = 1, [2, 3]
[2 * 1, ...double([2, 3])]
```

ここでreturnより先に関数が実行され最初に戻る。
処理2

```
head = 2, [3]
[2（最初に出る2）, 2 * 2, ...double([3])]
```

処理3

```
head = 3, []
[2, 4, 2 * 3, ...double([])]
```

処理4 if文でreturn []が返される。

```
[2, 4, 6, []]/こうなりそうだけどならないのが不思議です。
```

Comment: コードの出典は https://qiita.com/kawarayu/items/0f547d39c69de970834e#%E5%88%86%E5%89%B2%E4%BB%A3%E5%85%A5 でしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!head) { return []; }
```

で`head`が`undefined`の場合は空の配列を返しているので

```
double([1, 2, 3])
  double([2, 3])
    double([3])
       dobule([])
       // []
    // [2 * 3, ...[]] = [6]
  // [2 * 2, ...[6]] = [4, 6]
// [2 * 1, ...[4, 6]] = [2, 4, 6]
```

といったところでしょうか？

P.S. undefindではなくundefined，未定義です

Comment: 追記で考えてみたのですが、最後がどうしても`[2, 4, 6, []]`になる気がします。

Comment: 分りました！最後のリストはspreadで消えるのですね！！納得ですありがとうございます！！

Comment: はい。空であっても展開されるので結果として消えるようになりますね。

Comment: すいません。上のコードが理解できません。double([1, 2, 3])の際は[]のリストが吐き出されるのですか？流れがわからないです。

Comment: 回答に示したのはあくまでも処理の流れですが(インデントレベルの等しい呼び出しと返り値が対応します)、流れがわからない、というのであれば再帰の基本的な理解が足りていないように思えます。ざっくりとは、再帰は外側から内側に関数を呼び出していき、その返り値を内側から外側にまた伝えていくわけですが。。。(書いていておもったのですが、なにがわかっていてなにがわかっていないのか私にはわからないので上手くは伝えられそうにありません)